# Is <article> tag of HTML5 only to use in blogs?

Tags: html

Is the `article` tag of HTML5 only to use in blogs? Is it only for blog articles? Is it not to use for the content section of website, which is not a blog?

Generally I use

```
<div id="content">
<h2> title </h2>
<p> content </p>
</div>
```

Should I replace `div` with `article`

```
<article id="content">
<h2> title </h2>
<p> content </p>
</article>
```

or

```
<div id="content">
<article>
<h2> title </h2>
<p> content </p>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: The word "article" was never constrained to blogs anyway, seeing as "article" was used decades, even centuries, before "blog" existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-article-element):

> The article element represents a
>   component of a page that consists of a
>   self-contained composition in a
>   document, page, application, or site
>   and that is intended to be
>   independently distributable or
>   reusable, e.g. in syndication. This
>   could be a forum post, a magazine or
>   newspaper article, a blog entry, a
>   user-submitted comment, an interactive
>   widget or gadget, or any other
>   independent item of content.

So I guess it is quite dependant on what `#content` contains. If it would only contain that specific `article` (or stuff related to that `article`, like comments nested as further `article`s), you do not need the `div`.

[My favourite resource about this - HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/)

Comment: So there is no need in additional div?

Comment: On a website I have a page called "Company History" and I have content for that page which are some paragraphs and some images. It's just a page of small business website, it's not a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget. So  after your answer i think `article` tag is not required here.

Comment: If you have an *article* titled "Company History", with paragraphs and images, it looks like an *article* to me. Quite like a magazine or newspaper *article*. Notice the wording in the spec: **This could be a forum post, maga...**, it is not a restrictive list, just gives examples.

Comment: But I will not mention article's author at the end of the article

Comment: It's optional. It seems to me you are good to go with the `article` tag alone.

Answer (score 1):

There's some nice detail [about the article element at html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/).

In a nutshell, `<article>` is not limited to blogs and your example

```
<article id="content">
<h2> title </h2>
<p> content </p>
</article>
```

would seem to be an ideal use of `<article>`.

Answer (score 0):

One definition that I've read for the new  tag, which I find to be the most succinct, is the following:

> The article tag specifies independent, self-contained content.
>   An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to distribute it independently from the rest of the site.

Eg:
 - forum post
 - newspaper article
 - blog entry
 - user comment

If your content that you wish to wrap in  tags is self-contained and in a syndication context, then yes.  Then again, if the content is just the main section of a web page on a site, then I'd say, don't worry about it.